# Excel is broken with an IF formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

Can somebody explain what's wrong in my formula please?

[image: excel screenshot]

=IF(H88>=H87, "up", "dn")

Looked in a lotta places, can't figure what's wrong...

Comment: Are you sure you aren't supposed to use semicolons (`;`)? i.e. `=IF(H88>=H87; "up"; "dn")` Some regional settings (esp. in europe) have this as setting instead of commas.

Comment: If you have excel set in French, formulas written in English might not work. [You could try to use `SI(`](https://fr.excel-translator.de/si/).

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about the fact that in Europe commas are replaced by semicolons in formulas! And forgot that depending of country, the IF translates to local language! Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Correct formula is : =SI(H88>=H87; "up"; "dn")

Thanks to Jerry and Plutian!